# Automapper lazy loading. Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, automapper

I have an Entity and a ViewModel

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("DeliveryMethod")]
    public int DeliveryMethodId { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteDeliveryMethod DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? DeliveryMethodId { get; set; }
}
```

My controller receives the view model and uses automapper to map it back to the entity

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetQuote(OrderViewModel ordervm)
{
    Order order = Mapper.Map<Order>(ordervm);
    // Do something with the order...

    return View();
}
```

This is all fine, however after it has done the mapping back to an Order object it doesn't load the DeliveryMethod, DeliveryMethodId has a valid value, but DeliveryMethod is always null.

Shouldn't the DeliveryMethod load due to the lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper looks only at mapped properties. If you have not mapped destination property `DeliveryMethod` to any of source properties, then it will not be hit during mapping. If property getter is not executed, then entity is not lazy-loaded.

But even if this property was hit, it would not be lazy-loaded anyway. Because `Automapper` will create new instance of `Order` class during mapping. But for lazy-loading you need instance of [order proxy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) which have your `DbContext` inside. This proxy does loading of related entities when you try to read their values. With plain `Order` class instance lazy-loading cannot work.

Comment: But shouldn't it load when I access the DeliveryMethod via its getter then, or am I completely misunderstanding how the lazy loading works?

Comment: @Rumpetroll see my last update - without order proxy you cannot load navigation property

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, thanks. So is there any other option than for me to load the object in manually?

Comment: @Rumpetroll I would suggest to load it manually. I don't think your database queries should relay on mapper configuration. If you really need to load related entity during mapping, you can use `AfterMap` method of AutoMapper. But you should have access to `DbContext` at that point